# Vertices only showing up in small portion of data view when editing using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, vertices

When I'm trying to edit features, or even digitize new features, the vertices or new lines only show up in the bottom right corner of the data view.  I've tried restarting ArcMap and making sure only certain features are selectable, but the problem persists.  I basically have to hover over vertices and then place them blindly.  Once I save edits, the vertices show up wherever I moved them.  Same thing goes for new features.  I basically have to click blindly and once I double click it all shows up.  However, a small square in the bottom right portion of my screen works as its supposed to.  It is within the program though, because if I shrink the window down and move it around it does not affect where vertices are seen.  I saw a similar question ([Vertices not showing in Edit session (ArcMap 10.5)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259398) )that was answered through changing some properties, but I'm not sure I understand, and their issue was for the entire screen.
I'm editing vertices, but this also happens when I'm creating new features using the editing toolbar.  When you are editing a feature and you click on the edit vertices button, usually all of the vertices pop up and you can move them around, add more, delete them, etc.  I can find a vertice by hovering over certain places on the line (the vertices are actually there) I just can't see them.  I can even move them and edit them or delete them if I guess where they are correctly, I just cannot see any of this until after I save edits.

Comment: Mitchell, it doesn't look like your problem is the same as the issue in the link, since you are seeing part of it.  Are you editing a shapefile or a geodatabase file?  A lot of times editing shape files is more time consuming and may not draw properly.  If you're using a shapefile, try exporting it to a gdb.  Then I would bring the layer files into a new ArcMap document and see if it solves your problem.  If you don't know how to create a file geodatabase see: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/create-file-geodatabase.htm

Comment: (Last comment was too long so continuing) After your gdb is created to export right click on the shapefile and choose data>export, choose your output location (make sure the save as type is File and Personal Geodatabase feature class). Not sure if this will solve your issue but it's worth a try.